# Overring DialogFragment style by XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, styles

1. I'm looking for the correct attribute to override the DialogFragment style,
   I know for dialogs we can use :

   `<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">`
2. The correct `parent` to get the style from, as for `Dialog` it's :
   `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog`
   I believe its the same for the fragmentDialog but i'm not sure.

Thanks !